# How to do weighted fair task queues for CPU intensive tasks (in Python)?

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, task

## Problem

We run several calculations on geographical data from user input (called a "system"). Sometimes one system needs 10 locations to do calculations for, sometimes 1000+. One location takes approximately 1 second to calculate, hopefully we can speed this up in the future. We currently do this by using a multiprocessing `Pool` (from `billiard`) from within a Celery worker. This works in that it utilises all cores 100%, but there are two problems:

- There are lingering connections (`pipe`s, probably to the child procs) that cause the worker to hang when reaching the max open file limit (investigated, but haven't found a solution after more than a day of work)
- We can't spread the calculations over multiple machines.

To solve these problems, I would could run each calculation as a separate Celery task. However, we also want to schedule these calculations "fairly" for our users, so that:

*Users working on small systems (say <50 locations) don't have to wait until a large system (>1000 locations) is finished*. The larger the system, the less the increased waiting time matters to the user (they are doing something else anyway, and can get a notification). So this would be something akin to [Weighted fair queueing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_fair_queueing)
.

**I have not been able to find a distributed task runner that implements this possibility of prioritisation. Did I miss one?** I looked at [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), [RQ](http://python-rq.org/docs/workers/), [Huey](https://github.com/coleifer/huey), [MRQ](https://github.com/pricingassistant/mrq), [Pulsar Queue](https://github.com/quantmind/pulsar-queue) and some more, as well as into data processing pipelines like [Luigi](https://github.com/spotify/luigi) and [Pinball](https://github.com/pinterest/pinball), but none seem to easily enable this.

Most of these suggest creating priority by adding more workers for higher priority queues. However, that wouldn't work as the workers would start fighting for CPU time. (RQ does it differently by emptying *the complete* first passed in queue, before moving on to the next).

---

## Proposed architecture

What I imagine would work is running a multiprocessing program, with a process per CPU, that fetches, in a WFQ fashion, from multiple Redis lists, each being a certain queue.

**Would this be the right approach?** Of course there is quite some work to be done on making the queue configuration be dynamic (for example also storing it in Redis, and reloading it upon each couple of processed tasks), and getting event monitoring to be able to get insight.

Additional thoughts:

- Each task needs around 3MB of data, coming from Postgres, which is the same for each location in the system (or at least per a couple of 100 locations). With the current approach, this resides in the shared memory, and each process can access it quickly. I'll probably have to setup a local Redis instance on each machine to cache this data to, so not every process is going to fetch it over and over again.
- I keep hitting up on [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/), and it has a lot of enticing possibilities, but besides maybe the monitoring, it doesn't seem to be a good fit. Or am I wrong?
- What would make more sense: running each worker as a separate program, and managing it with something like supervisor, or starting a single program, that forks a child for each CPU (no CPU count config necessary), and maybe also monitors its children for stuck processes?
- We already run both RabbitMQ and Redis, so I could also use RMQ for the queues. It seems to me the only thing gained by using RMQ is the possibility of not losing tasks on worker crash by using acknowledgements, at the cost of using a more difficult library/complicated protocol.

Any other advice?